# Please explain the meaning in the context

Tags: grammar, british-english

Question:
I have been told by my instructor that you need to question who or what to the verb to get the direct object. Also she said that wherever there are prepositional phrases there is no object.

> "He invited us to his birthday celebration."

Please justify why the sentence has a direct object. Also please explain what is a prepositional phrase in the context and why it is so?

Comment: He invited **who**? He invited **us**. There is your direct object.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Thanks but what are the direct questions tobe asked to the verb for the same purpose?

Comment: *invited* is your verb. Ask the verb: invited who? Answer: invited us.

Comment: To get your verb, you've to see which part of the sentence is 'expressing action': there you've your verb— Clearly, it's _'invited'_ in your sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, a indirect object stands between the verb and the direct object. If an indirect object is to follow the direct object, it must be part of a prepositional phrase.

> - He gave me the book.
> - He gave the book *to me.*

Perhaps this is where your assertion comes from; here we have a prepositional phrase instead of an indirect object. Certainly there is no reason to say that wherever there are prepositional phrases there is no object, and your own example proves that's not true.

*Fowler* (3rd edn) puts it thus

> In grammar, the person
> or thing secondarily affected by the
> action stated in the verb, if expressed by
> a noun alone (i.e. without *to, for,* etc.), is
> called the indirect object. In Latin and
> Greek it is recognizable, as it once was
> in English, by being in the dative, while
> the direct object is in the accusative. The
> English dative now having no separate
> form, the indirect object must be
> otherwise identified, usu. by the fact that
> it stands between the verb and the direct
> object (e.g. *Hand me that book*), and, if it
> is to follow the direct object, must be
> replaced by a prepositional phrase (e.g.
> *Hand that book* to me).
>
> Variations are
>
> 1. when no direct object is expressed, as in
>    *You told me yourself;*
> 2. when the direct
>    object is a mere pronoun and is allowed
>    to precede, as *I told it you before* (but not
>    *I told the story you before*);
> 3. when the
>    indirect object comes after a passive
>    verb, as *It was told me in confidence.*
>
> Note:
> Variations (2) and (3) are now distinctly
> archaic. A speaker would now be more
> likely to say *I told you that* (or *about it*)
> *before; it was told to me in confidence.*

Comment: I don't see any signs of an indirect object in the OP's example.

Answer (score 3):

The quintessential English sentence *John hit the ball* has the syntactic constituent order "*Subject + Verb + NP (*Object*)*." This is pretty much the case with your sentence, only that it has a *PP* (*to his birthday party*) tacked at the end. You can say that *prepositional phrase* (*PP*) is nothing but a group of words that starts with a preposition (*to* here), and essentially does the work of a preposition. That's all there is to it ( at least, on a rudimentary level.)

Comment: You might add that the PP "to his birthday celebrations" is a complement of "invite", thus the latter has two complements.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for your fine inputs (as always.) But I'm afraid adding this bit might confuse OP as it would be segueing from the traditional framework to the modern approach (_complement_ vs _object_.) If, however, you want to flesh out my answer, you're welcome. :-)

Comment: But the purpose of ELU is to give answers that linguists can appreciate; questions 'requiring' less complete answers belong elsewhere.

Comment: I agree with you @Edwin Ashworth, but the point is that adding details that, while 'completing' the answer, lead to confusion in OP's mind, defeats the purpose of answering a question in the first place. I know this answer leaves out a lot, but I'm fairly certain it touches upon the principal demand of the question.

Answer (score -7):

A prepositional phrase is a sentence fragment - a phrase - that begins with a preposition (in your example 'to') and has an object (in your example 'his birthday celebration').

In this case, it's merely acting as a replacement for an object, you can regard it as an expansion of the notion of an object.

For example, in the sentence:

> The ball hit back across John's head after bouncing off the wall

The phrase 'across John's head after bouncing off the wall' is a prepositional phrase introduced by the preposition 'across'.

Comment: @Greybeard: I rolled-back your intervention. Whilst it's fine to correct my punctuation, I don't see why you felt it necessary to correct my prose. It was already clear.

Comment: Above comment edited. Personal attacks are not allowed.

Comment: @MoziburUllah *The ball hit back across John's head* is not at all idiomatic and I suspect, ungrammatical. I feel it would have helped had you explained to the OP that a prepositional phrase comprises a preposition plus noun phrase as object.

Comment: @Greybeard: It seems fine to me. Your suspicion is just that, a suspicion. And in my view, suspect. Can you provide a reference to back up your 'suspicion'?